# Sanity unauthorized Issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I have created a project in next.js with sanity. When I run sanity studio, it gives unauthorized error

> You are not authorized to access this studio.
>
> Maybe you could ask someone to invite you to collaborate on this project?
>
> If you think this is an error, verify that you are signed in with the correct account. You are currently signed in as <my name - my email> through Google.

I have already logged in to sanity studio but still I got an error.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In my case it looked like sanity auto logged me in when creating sanity project from the terminal. I did not want that to happen. instead I wanted to be logged out and create the sanity project by choosing a login method (ex: google login) and from that step to choose the login account of my preference. Therefore instead of issuing: **npm create sanity@latest**

I found out from sanity documentation (https://www.sanity.io/docs/create-a-sanity-project) under the "trouble installing?" section the following command where it seems firstly a logout is done before creating the sanity project

```
npx sanity@latest logout && npm create sanity@latest -- --template clean --create-project "Sanity project" --dataset production
```

This fixed my issue and I did not get the authentication error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and didn't want to try Ashley's answer (re-set up my sanity). For me, google auth didn't work but GitHub auth worked for some reason. (maybe I had earlier logged in, also I checked my admin account setup and it didn't specify GitHub auth but just the google account I use across).